# Function with vector parameter not shown in OnDelta Editor // Unity 2019.2.6f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I´m using the Lean Touch+ Asset to implement drag and drop for 3D objects. Unfortunately the needed function is not showing up in the OnDelta() event editor.

[image: EventInspector]

The example is working, but showing  in the event editor. Also I tried an older 2018 unity version and there it works fine. Anyway I´d like to use the newer one. 
If I change the Vector2 to a float, it gets listed in the editor, but Vector2 should work as well or am I wrong?

This code is not complete, because it´s not mine and I´m not sure if I can just share it. But I hope it helps understanding my problem.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

namespace Lean.Touch
{
[HelpURL(LeanTouch.PlusHelpUrlPrefix + "LeanManualTranslate")]
[AddComponentMenu(LeanTouch.ComponentPathPrefix + "Manual Translate")]

public class LeanManualTranslate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void TranslateAB(Vector2 magnitude)
    {
        Translate(DirectionA * magnitude.x + DirectionB * magnitude.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two types of callbacks for [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityEvents.html)

> - **Static**
>     Static calls are preconfigured calls, with preconfigured values that are set in the UI. This means that when the callback is invoked, the target function is invoked with the argument that has been entered into the UI.
> - **Dynamic**
>     Dynamic calls are invoked using an argument that is sent from code, and this is bound to the type of UnityEvent that is being invoked. The UI filters the callbacks and only shows the dynamic calls that are valid for the UnityEvent.

`UI` refers to the Inspector in the Unty Editor here.

**BUT** .. unfortunately there is a **Bug** in newer versions so [dynamic parameters do not work with `UnityEvent`](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type) currently. 

(Fixed in `2019.3` and `2020.1` ... don't use those though as the are still in Alpha & Beta state!)

---

In general `Vector2` was afaik never a  parameter to be displayed and edited via the Inspector when choosing a **static** callback type and was only applicable for passing it to a **dynamic** callback.

Only the basic types like `int`, `string`, `float`, `bool` and `Object` references work for the **static** ones.

---

As a workaround you can still add callbacks on runtime via script - though it is kind of shitty and only makes sense if the target component sits on the same GameObject as the one with the `UnityEvent`

```c#
public class LeanManualTranslate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        GetComponent<LeanMultiSet>().OnDelta.AddCallback(TranslateAB);
    }

    private void TranslateAB(Vector2 magnitude)
    {
        Translate(DirectionA * magnitude.x + DirectionB * magnitude.y);
    }
}
```

---

Or alternatively stick with `2019.1.14` where it works as well. There bug seems to be introduced since `2019.2`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, it helped a lot! :)